# Service Worker Push Notification API Subscription .Net Core 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, push-notification, service-worker

I have been stuck on this one for a few days and have worked through many issues. I must be missing something simple but not sure what it is. I got a lot of this code from other samples I have found. It definitely needs some cleaning and error handling which I will resolve once I get it to actually work.

When I post to a simple Blazor Page, the `OnInitializedAsync` Fires, yet when I create an API it simply will not fire. Postman fires the API just fine with a response of 200. However the JS service worker returns undefined as the API never hits.

I tried to make it as readable as possible, please forgive all the breaks.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>PWS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button onclick="main()">Enable notification</button>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
const checkPermission = () => {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
      throw new Error("No support for sevice worker!");
    }
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {
      throw new Error("No support for notification API");
    }
  }      
  const registerSW = async () => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
    return registration;
  }

  const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

    if (permission !== 'granted') {
      throw new Error("Notification permission not granted");
    } else {
      new Notification("Hello World");
    }
  }

  const main = async () => {
    checkPermission();
    await requestNotificationPermission();
    await registerSW();
  }
```

**SERVICE-WORKER.JS**

```
const urlBase64ToUint8Array = base64String => {
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding)
      .replace(/\-/g, '+')
      .replace(/_/g, '/');

    const rawData = atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
      outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return outputArray;
  }


  const saveSubscription = async (subscription) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7184/api/SaveSubscription', {
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        accept: "*/*",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Content-Length': "",
            'Host': ""
        },
        body: subscription
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error)
      return response;
    }
  }

  self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    console.log(e.type)
  })

  self.addEventListener('activate', async (e) => {
    const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: (urlBase64ToUint8Array("BMHcy1n...")) // Key Omitted Here
    });

    console.log('Subscription: ' + JSON.stringify(subscription));
    const response = await saveSubscription(subscription);
    console.log('Response: ' + response);
  })

  self.addEventListener("push", e => {
    self.registration.showNotification("Title IS HERE!", { body: e.data.text(), icon: "favicon.ico"} )
  })

  saveSubscription();
```

**.NET CORE 6**

**MODELS**

*KEYS MODEL*

```
namespace ServiceWorkerSubscription.Controllers;
public class keysModel
{
  public string p256dh { get; set; }
  public string auth { get; set; }
}
```

*PUSH NOTIFICATION MODEL*

```
namespace ServiceWorkerSubscription.Controllers;
 public class PushNotificationModel
 {
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    public string? expirationTime { get; set; }
    public keysModel keys { get; set; }
 }
```

*PUSH NOTIFICATION PAYLOAD MODEL*

```
namespace ServiceWorkerSubscription.Controllers;
public class PushNotificationPayloadModel
{
  public string Msg { get; set; }
  public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

**API**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WebPush;  // Using WebPush for now just to get something working as all the samples show this usage.

namespace ServiceWorkerSubscription.Controllers
  {
      [Route("api/[controller]")]
      [ApiController]
      public class SaveSubscription : ControllerBase
      {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] PushNotificationModel subscription)
        {
          var pushSubscription = new PushSubscription(subscription.endpoint, subscription.keys.p256dh, subscription.keys.auth);
          var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails("mailto: <me@me.com>", "BMHcy1nHG...", "h2N4..."); // Keys Omitted Here

          var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
          webPushClient.SetVapidDetails(vapidDetails);

          // send notification
          var payload = new PushNotificationPayloadModel
          {
            Msg = "Thank you for subscribing",
            Icon = "[URL to an image to display in the notification]"
          };

          try
          {
            await webPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(pushSubscription, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), vapidDetails);
          }
          catch (WebPushException exception)
          {
            var statusCode = exception.StatusCode;
            return new StatusCodeResult((int)statusCode);
          }

          return new OkResult();
        }
      }
  }
```

I have attached some screenshots to show what is happening.
FYI: With the images, I have omitted the keys but they are there in full when running.

As you can see when using Postman, the API fires. When I run the HTML page the API never fires. One note, when the API is not running, the service worker takes a little longer to come back then when the API is running. This is leading me to believe there is a flaw in the API possibly as the 'undefined' response comes back fast when the API is running but again never fires. Any insight would be amazing.

[image: Edge]

[image: Postman]

[image: Visual Studio API]